# why mysql5.5 AUTO_INCREMENT dose not affect?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Here is my question:
I have a table (InnoDB)， the max primary-key value is 5000000, that user 
**ALTER TABLE tb SET AUTO_INCREMENT  = 20000;**
When I do that on local, it's OK；
But on server, the AUTO_INCREMENT is still 5000000.
Is anybody can help me?

Comment: Please update your question to include the output of `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM DatabaseName WHERE name LIKE 'TableName';` before your ALTER TABLE command and after your command.

Answer (score 0):

@Inkparker this should work.

```
ALTER TABLE tb AUTO_INCREMENT = 5000000;
```